# Move Symbol in The Direction of a Point

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a `Bullet` symbol on my stage, but I want to move it towards a `Point` at a given `speed`. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify which version of ActionScript you're using but, if it's ActionScript 2.0, you can move a symbol as long as it is a `MovieClip` type and you give it an instance name. In ActionScript 3.0 I think you can also move a `Button` symbol,

The easiest way to move the symbol to a new point would be to use a tween library such as [Greensock's TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) which is pretty much the standard for movement in Flash. If you're using ActionScript 3.0, you could use the built in [`Tween`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html) class. Either of these will allow you to move the object over a duration which you can specify in either seconds or frames.